# How to implement CAF Receiver Queueing

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm confused by this page https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_features#queueing

It seems to assume that any implementation of 'YourServer' will return synchronous results rather than promises or observables.

Does anyone have a working example where the queue is managed by an http based service?

Edit:

I've found one major problem with this page. It inconsistently names the `cast.framework.QueueBase` base class. In some places it correctly names it `cast.framework.QueueBase` while in others it names it `cast.framework.messages.QueueBase`. In particular, the link to the class documentation uses the wrong name. The correct link is to https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.QueueBase.

This helps a lot since it says fetchItems and its siblings return:

"(non-null Array of non-null cast.framework.messages.QueueItem or non-null Promise containing non-null Array of non-null cast.framework.messages.QueueItem)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there were bugs in the documentation. I reported these on the Google+ [community](https://plus.google.com/communities/115742157569103585450) and they are now fixed.

I've got a sample queueing receiver working and made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jcable/45c65a72074763a9ec30ddb1ff217517) of it.